# how do you prevent magento logging out after non activity

Tags: magento-1.9

is it possible to prevent magento from logging you out of the admin area after non activity. It's difficult when entering products and then getting sidetracked on other jobs, and then when coming back then system logs you out.

Any way to prevent this ?

Answer (score 3):

system->configuration->admin->security->Session Lifetime (seconds)

Simply increase that value to something more acceptable for you.

Comment: Caveat: server-based session times have final say.

Comment: And link quality as well.

Comment: @FiascoLabs "link quality"?

Comment: Yep, I can stay on most of the day at home, indefinitely if on the internal dev server (different server), but from at work, the Admin backend has a random uptime from minutes to over an hour. Home's broadband, work's bonded T1 and dev is ethernet. Others have noticed that quality of the internet connection has something to do with it as well. There may be nothing you can do with settings to keep the backend up for long periods.

Comment: The value set in here is currently 14000 which equates to 3,8 hours.. However this logs us out within half a hour usually

Comment: @MarcSmith Sometimes you are lucky, and that works. As mentioned by other comments, server configuration can override this.